# Finding the money isn't easy or money being found isn't easy?

Tags: passive-voice, gerunds

1. **Finding** **the** **money** isn't easy.
2. It isn't easy **Finding** **the** **money**.

Is it possible to use passive gerund '**money** **being** **found**' instead of '**Finding** **the** **money**'?
e.g:

3. **money** **being** **found** isn't easy.
4. It isn't easy **money** **being** **found**.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 is a correct way to describe financial difficulty.

Sentence 2 is also correct, except for the capitalization of "Finding".

The passive-voice sentences 3 and 4 are not possible.  Consider that the main verb of the sentence is *is*.  Ask yourself, *what* isn't easy?  Answer: the act of *finding* is difficult.  The goal is not to describe the money itself as being easy or hard.  Furthermore, that would leave "being found" dangling in those sentences with no logical purpose.

On the contrary, money lying around, waiting to be found, is what I would call easy money!  That is probably quite the opposite of that you had in mind, and a rare statement to make.  Therefore, I'd be careful not to say anything that sounds like that, and might be misinterpreted as such.

Comment: so,is it impossible to use passive gerund clause as a subject of verb?

Comment: "My phone getting dropped turned out well: I ended up getting a free upgrade to the latest model."